# Scala Tuple10 implicit ordering not working

Tags: scala, implicit

I can get compare method work upto Tuple9 like following:

```
  import scala.math.Ordered.orderingToOrdered
  (1,2,"ab",4,5,6.0,7l,"de",1.0) compare (1,2,"ab",4,5,6.0,7l,"de",1.0)
```

But with Tuple10 I get compile error:

```
  import scala.math.Ordered.orderingToOrdered
  (1,2,"ab",4,5,6.0,7l,"de",1.0,2) compare (1,2,"ab",4,5,6.0,7l,"de",1.0,2) // >> compile error: value compare is not a member of (Int, Int, String, Int, Int, Double, Long, String, Double, Int)
```

I tried alternate way but that also gives implicit error:

```
implicitly[Ordering[Tuple10[Int, Int, String, Int, Int, Double, Long, String, Double, Double]]].compare((1,2,"ab",4,5,6.0,7l,"de",1.0,4), (1,2,"ab",4,5,6.0,7l,"de",1.0,4)) 

compiler error:
No implicit Ordering defined for (Int, Int, String, Int, Int, Double, Long, String, Double, Double).
not enough arguments for method implicitly: (implicit e: Ordering[(Int, Int, String, Int, Int, Double, Long, String, Double, Double)])Ordering[(Int, Int, String, Int, Int, Double, Long, String, Double, Double)]. Unspecified value parameter e.
```

Looks like Ordering is defined for only till Tuple9. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L363), you are correct, it only goes to Tuple9.  But after you've seen the pattern in each iteration you should be able to copy and extend it as needed.

Comment: thanks. what would be best place to add such extension. I know within a scope its available but to make it more global is it better to put it in some utility object and do imports of implicit?